# subprocess timeout when exceeds a certain time limit

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm using the subprocess module of python to run an ssh command over my servers for collecting their disk usage. The one thing on which i'm stuck is if the `ssh` is not configured in any server then subprocess prompt for the password input which makes my whole script stuck and then i have to voluntarily kill the script itself. I just want it to let go all the servers which asks for password prompt(where ssh is not configured) and continue processing the rest.

```
def MyFunction(server):
   msg=""
   ps = subprocess.Popen("ssh -l mygroup %s 'df -k /some/directory'" % server,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
   out, err = ps.communicate()
   if err != None:
      msg += "\n"+err
   else:
      msg = out
   return msg


server_list= ['server A','server B','server C','server D']
for server in server_list:
    Final_msg+=MyFunction(server)
```

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: It would be helpful when you'd post the real code. Especially if `server` and `servers` is not interchanged... and fixing the indenting might be useful as well.

Comment: yeah about indentation, i think there's some problem in the site or maybe it's just my browser, sorry

Comment: Might want to look into [`fabric`](http://www.fabfile.org)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is just the thing that you want to avoid `ssh` ask you for anything, then you can forbid it to do so.

You can use the SSH option

> BatchMode
>
> If set to “yes”, passphrase/password querying will be disabled.
>   This option is useful in scripts and other batch jobs where no user is present to supply the password.
>   The argument must be “yes” or “no”. The default is “no”.

So just add `-o BatchMode=yes`:

```
ps = subprocess.Popen("ssh -o BatchMode=yes -l mygroup %s 'df -k /some/directory'" % server, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

BTW, why do you need `shell=True` here? Better do

```
ps = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "-o", "BatchMode=yes", "-l", "mygroup", server, "df -k /some/directory"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

as it is cleaner, safer and internally simpler.

Comment: `command-line line 0: Missing yes/no argument.` i get this error for every ssh.

Comment: i did `ps = subprocess.Popen("ssh -o BatchMode=yes -l mygroup %s 'df -k /some/directory'" % server, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)` now it's not prompting for anything

Comment: @Disturbed_Entity thx, I added this. But you should definitely think about dropping that `shell=True`. Together with ssh, it makes things even more complicated.